# Making a file protected with the same system than the endpoint available in an Ember app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

The ember App run on top of a rails API.

For authentication It uses a token header (with devise server side)

I have an index action that return a CSV when the request add .csv to the URL :

```
        respond_to do |format|
          format.json {json_response @custormer_info_requests.page(@page).per(@size)}
          format.csv {send_data @custormer_info_requests.to_csv, filename: "demandes.csv"}
        end
```

The problem is that a direct link like this :  `<a href='/marketadmin_api/v1/customer_info_requests.csv?partner_id={{partner.id}}'>File</a>`

Fails with a 401 because there is no auth header.

How do you allow users to download protected files ?

Answer (score 0):

You have few options:

1. Fetch file with javascript (you can read how to download binary data with jquery [here](http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/)) and then use [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to initiate "download" dialog. You might want to replace link with button and show some spinner while file is fetching. You can also pre-fetch it if file is not too big and you are 80% sure user would want to download it.

   1a. If front-end has data already, you can form csv on client (using papaparse or [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-array-to-csv), for example) and use FileSaver to allow user to save it. This saves you from extra requests. To save file from csv-string: `saveAs(new Blob([csvString], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' }), 'file-name.csv');`

   1b. Fetch json, convert it to csv on client and use FileSaver to save it.
2. Add auth token as get parameter to link and teach backend to understand it

```
  <a href='/marketadmin_api/v1/customer_info_requests.csv?partner_id={{partner.id}}&auth={{token}}'>File</a>
```